# JPA Criteria API for WITH clause and subquery in FROM clause

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, criteria-api

I`m new to JPA and I would like to implement a query that contains WITH clause, and also subquery in FROM clause by using JPA Criteria API, for example:

```
WITH A AS(...) SELECT a1,a2 FROM A
```

and also:

```
SELECT b1, b2 FROM (SELECT c1,c2 FROM ...)
```

How do I supposed to achieve this goal by using JPA Criteria? Or is there any alternative solution is fine.

thanks for helping

Comment: Not possible. The obfuscation layer won't let you use modern SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible with JPQL/HQL and the reason is simple, this is not an entity based approach. The core concept for ORM's are entities and they operate on that level.

There's nothing wrong with plain SQL if you want to have efficient queries, just make sure you understand the implications using it.

Comment: How can I use WITH in plain sql? I tried doing it and it says unexpected token.

Comment: @nirvair `@Query(value = "<your native/plain SQL query here>", nativeQuery = true)`